# Aesthetics for graphs in R WITHOUT using ggplot

Tags: plot, histogram, aesthetics

I looked for the easthetics to make the histogram look better in my R code, nonetheless I was wondering if I could change the size of the bins or maybe the margin or put a color background in the plot **WITHOUT** using ggplot.

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, you should just use ggplot